# Dynamically selecting variables from a dataset in sas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to read a data set that has columns like below:

```
1000 10001 1002 2000 2002 2004 2006
a    b     c    d    e    f    g
b    c     d    e    f    g    h
```

The format of the column names is number. I need to read this data and dynamically select the columns, say I want to read only columns 2000 to 2004.

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly. But there are many ways to get variables dynamically.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Is this data in a SAS dataset? (I suspect not, SAS variable names can't be numeric).  Is it in a text file that you are trying to read into a SAS dataset?  What do you mean by dynamically select columns to be read?  Also, show what code you have tried, and describe how it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use proc import in SAS, it will automatically convert the numeric field names into character by adding "_"(underscore) prefix. Assuming that your file is tab delimited, then following simple code will work:

```
proc import datafile="Y:\Temp\numbers.txt" /*Name/Path of your text file*/
dbms=dlm
out=mydata
replace;
delimiter='09'x; /*Tab Delimiter*/
getnames=yes;
run;

proc print data=mydata; run;
```

You will get following output:

[image]

Once, you have your desired dataset, then you can keep/drop required variables.